# Android intercept file transfer over Bluetooth

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, file-transfer

Can we intercept file transfer over Bluetooth on android? or can we listen for file transfer status i.e delivered, failed, start, cancel...etc, is there a Broadcast Intent Action for that?
I don't want transfer files from my app what I want is listen for transfer events from android built-in bluetooth application.

Comment: Far too many questions in one that is hard to make out what is it you're really looking for. What have you researched/done?

Comment: @t0mm13b The main question is "can we listen for file transfer status i.e delivered, failed, start, cancel...etc?"

Comment: Did you manage to track transfer status?